# How can add a UIPickerView in a UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

[image]

I've created a `UIAlertController` with a `UITextfield` and a `UIPickerview`.

When I press the button to present the UIAlert the `UIPickerView` is totally displaced. How can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```swift
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
           return 1
       }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return passwordCategory.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        passwordCategory[row]
    }




 func passwordAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "type in some text", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (passwordCategoryTextfield) in
            passwordCategoryTextfield.placeholder = "e.g Business"
        }
        let pickerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 300)
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: pickerFrame)
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        alert.view.addSubview(picker)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "add", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            let passwordInfo = alert.textFields?.first?.text
            self.individualPasswordInformaiton.insert("\(passwordInfo ?? "")", at: 0)
            print(self.individualPasswordInformaiton)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: It would be better if you were to create a custom `UIViewController` for this. It's not recommended to add subviews in a `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify UIAlertController. Instead, make an ordinary custom presented view controller. Now the interface is up to you. If you like, you can make your presented view controller's look and act just like a UIAlertController's view (as I demonstrate [here](https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7)).